# Error en la paginación me salen de mas (Resumido)

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con la paginación de mis registros que se muestran en mi tabla, y es que me aparecen de mas en la paginación y este no llega a tope como debería de ser.

Tengo una tabla la cual muestro mis registros y ahí todo bien el detalle es con la consulta de una tabla el cual cuento el numero de columnas y esto lo tomo para la paginación pero no me resulta.

**La tabla donde muestro mis registros:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La siguiente tabla muestro que la paginación sobrepasa los registros el cual si voy hasta el ultimo numero de la paginación este esta en blanco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago uso del buscador el mismo problema, si me muestra los que quiero pero en la paginación muestra de mas.

**Ósea que debería mostrar el total y si voy hasta el ultimo numero de la paginación debería de mostrar el total de lo que tengo e igual cuando busco algo.**

Este es la parte del código:

Donde en esta parte debería y es usada por la otra consulta del conteo de columnas pero la uso aparte por que no me da como quiero, pero si me pueden ayudar para que lo tome de la consulta original.

```
$q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $sTable = "facturas f JOIN clientes c JOIN users u JOIN medicos m JOIN detalle_factura d JOIN productos p";
    $sWhere = "";
    $sWhere.=" ON f.id_cliente = c.id_cliente AND f.id_vendedor = u.user_id AND f.id_medico = m.id_medico AND d.id_producto = p.id_producto AND d.numero_factura = f.numero_factura";
    if ( $_GET['q'] != "" ) {
        $sWhere.= " and (c.nombre_cliente like '%$q%' or f.numero_factura like '%$q%' or f.debe1 like '%$q%' or f.total_venta like '%$q%' or f.estatus like '%$q%' or m.nombre_medico like '%$q%' or p.nombre_producto like '%$q%')";
    }
    $sWhere.=" GROUP BY c.id_cliente,f.numero_factura order by f.fecha_factura desc";
    
    $tabla = "facturas f, clientes c, productos p, detalle_factura d";
    $donde="where f.id_cliente = c.id_cliente and f.numero_factura = d.numero_factura and d.id_producto = p.id_producto";
    if ( $_GET['q'] != "" ) {
        $donde.= " and (c.nombre_cliente like '%$q%' or f.numero_factura like '%$q%' or f.debe1 like '%$q%' or f.total_venta like '%$q%' or f.estatus like '%$q%' or p.nombre_producto like '%$q%')";
    }
    $donde.="";
```

**Donde esto:**

```
$count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $tabla $donde");
```

Deberia ser asi:

```
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable $sWhere");
```

Comment: No es que no te queramos ayudar es que da mucha pereza leer todo ese código. Intenta resumir a la parte donde obtienes el  `count` de todos los datos   y a la parte donde imprimes el paginado

Comment: @WilfredoAleman Buenas tardes Wilfredo, lo resumí lo mas que pude, espero me puedan ayudar que de verdad desde hace días que no lo puedo resolver. Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo en responder.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes.

**Primero :** Debemos tener claro que para la paginación de alguna manera debemos  obtener un parámetro `pagina` que indicara la pagina que se deberá mostrar.(esto lo solucionamos utilizando la variable `$_GET['pagina']`) .

**Segundo :**  Debemos tener un parámetro  `itemsPorPagina` el cual indicara la cantidad máxima de elementos por pagina ese.

Estos dos elementos  se deben enviar a la consulta `sql` para indicar el los elementos que debe devolver aquí un ejemplo simple:

```html
$pagina = 2;
$itemsPorPagina= 12;

//mutiplicamos la pagina por la cantidad de items por pagina
$desde = $pagina * $itemsPorPagina;

$sql ="select * from faturas limit $desde,$itemsPorPagina";
# Salida =  select * from faturas limit 24,12
```

Aclarado esto  el código será el siguiente:

```html
<?php
//Esta variable deberia ser el resultado de tu select count *
$cantidad = 500;
$cantidadpaginas = 15; // paginas entre anterior y siguiente
$url ="paginacion.php";

#cantida totales de servicios
$itemsPorPagina = 12;
$num_paginas = ceil($cantidad / $itemsPorPagina );

if(!isset($_GET["pagina"])) $pagina = 1;
else $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];

 
 //buscamos la pagina final
 $lista_paginas = "";
 $pagina_inicial = $pagina;
 if($pagina_inicial + $cantidadpaginas > $num_paginas) $pagina_final =  $num_paginas;
 else $pagina_final = $pagina_inicial + $cantidadpaginas;


 $anterior = $pagina - 1;
 $siguiente = $pagina + 1;
?>
```

Ahora el código HTML + PHP encargado de imprimir la paginación

```html
<!--INICIO_PAGINACION-->
<footer>
        <div class="paginacion">
            <p class="mostrando">Mostrando página <span><?=$pagina?></span> de <span><?=$num_paginas?></span> ( <span><?=$cantidad?> resultados</span> )</p>
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <?php 
                        if($anterior >=1 ) {
                            echo "<li>
                             <a  href='$url?pagina=$anterior'>Anterior</a>  
                            </li>";
                        }
                
                        //imprimir empaginado
                        for ($i=$pagina_inicial; $i<=$pagina_final; $i++) {  
                            if ($i != $pagina_inicial){
                                echo "<li class=\"page-item\"><a href=\"$url?pagina=$i\" class=\"page-link\" title=\"P&aacute;gina $i\">$i</a></li>";
                            }else echo "<li class=\"page-item active\">$i</li>";
                            
                        }
                    
                
                        if($anterior <= $num_paginas ) {
                            echo "<li>
                             <a  href='$url?pagina=$anterior'>Anterior</a>  
                            </li>";
                        }
                    ?>
                
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
</footer>
    <!--FIN_PAGINACION-->
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Wilfredo Aleman, lo checare bien paso por paso e iré implementándolo, ya te digo que tal me resulto, y una vez mas gracias por tu pronta respuesta y por tu apoyo.